# Reading a file into an array of lines in a system-independent manner

Tags: node.js

In Node.js, when I want to read the lines of a file into an array, I do:

```
fs.readFileSync(filename).split('\r\n')
```

but this doesn't work on Linux. On Linux, I can do:

```
fs.readFileSync(filename).split('\n')
```

but this doesn't work on Windows. I can also do:

```
fs.readFileSync(filename).split(/[\r\n]+/)
```

which works on both systems, but hard to read.

Is there a simple, system-independent way to read a file into an array of lines in Node.js?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use constant for such needs:

```
var nl = require('os').EOL;
```

So it would look like:

```
var nl = require('os').EOL;
fs.readFileSync(filename).split(nl);
```

Or you could use just RegExp:

```
fs.readFileSync(filename).split(/\r?\n/)
```

Comment: Still it does not guarantees that it will work all the time, especially when files or data is cross-streamed over different OS. So second option would be sort of more stable. But first option is great if you know that data does not travel a lot around.